# Type Checking in VSCode with JSDoc With Passed Type Defs

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I am experimenting with JSDoc and VS Code for type checking and I'm wondering if there is a way type checking can be done in such a way where a type is set and then when the aforementioned type is then passed into a function - we do not have to re-delcare the type.

For example:

```
/**
* @type {string}
*/
const result = someFunction1(args);

someFunction2(result)

//here - when I type result * 5... VS code announces an error... great! work as expected


const someFunction2 = (result)=>{
//here - when I type result * 5... VS code does NOT announce an error... :( I was hoping it would...
}
```

Is there a way to get VSCode to announce an error without having to re-declare `@type {string}`?
`

Comment: In `someFunction2`, `result` is an argument local to that function that shadows the first `const result`. It's a totally different variable. So VSCode probably thinks that is untyped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In someFunction2, result is an argument local to that function that shadows the first const result. It's a totally different variable. So VSCode probably thinks that is untyped.

I first posted this as a comment since I wasn't sure if it was you're whole problem, but maybe it was :)